# Java BigDecimal bugs with String constructor to rounding with ROUND_HALF_UP

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm trying to implement a new grade rounding to BigDecimal class, and I'm getting a possible bug, must probably I doing something wrong. The code below exposes my problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal(0.35);
    valDouble = valDouble.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(valDouble.doubleValue()); // prints 0.3

    BigDecimal valString = new BigDecimal(new String("0.35"));
    valString = valString.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(valString.doubleValue()); // prints 0.4
}
```

My doubt here is, is BigDecimal different for double and String constructors?

I can't understand this 'bug', at least, I just used a simple string concat to 'solve' it, as below:

```
BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal("" + 0.35);
```

Any idea what could be causing this odd behavior?

Comment: No idea what you are tying to ask here.  Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbp-3BJWsU8&feature=player_detailpage#t=243s) may interest you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a bug. 0.35 as a double literal represents a value that is not exactly equal to 0.35; it's likely something like 0.349999995 or something. So it rounds down.

The String constructor lets you specify 0.35 exactly using "0.35", and that rounds up.

Don't use the `double` constructor here; when it matters enough to use `BigDecimal` you need to stay out of floating-point land.

Comment: I saw this on Google I/O Java puzzlers
.

Comment: I thing it was [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbp-3BJWsU8&feature=player_detailpage#t=243s) puzzler :)

Comment: Yup. Worth watching, everyone.

Comment: Perfect Sean...primary mistake :/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to guess what 0.35 is represent as

```
BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal(0.35);
System.out.println(valDouble);
```

prints

```
0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
```

This will round down to 1 decimal place as 0.3

You don't need to convert to a String, you can use `valueOf`

```
BigDecimal valDouble = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.35);
System.out.println(valDouble);
```

prints

```
0.35
```

To round half up to one decimal place you can use

```
double d = 0.35;
double d1 = Math.round(d * 10) / 10.0;
System.out.println(d1);
```

prints

```
0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

0.35 is already inexact, became of the binary radix of FP. Use new BigDecimal("0.35"), which is exact, because of the decimal radix.