# BigDecimal multiply by zero

Tags: java, bigdecimal, numerical-analysis, rounding-error

I am performing a simple multiplication with BigDecimal and I have found some strange behaviour when multiplying by zero (multiplying by zero is correct in this use-case).

Basic maths tells me that anything multiplied by zero will equal zero (see:[Zero Product Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property) and [Multiplication Properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Properties))

However, the following code will consistently fail with the same error:

```
assertEquals(new BigDecimal(0), new BigDecimal(22.3).multiply(new BigDecimal(0)));
```

> ```
> java.lang.AssertionError: 
> Expected :0
> Actual   :0E-48
> ```

Is this an inaccuracy with BigDecimal or is there some niche branch of maths that I'm missing somewhere?

Notes: JDK 1.6.0_27 running in IntelliJ 11

Comment: Yes look into numerical analysis and especially approximation and truncation error

Comment: Or in `double` you could write `assertEquals(0, 23.3 * 0, 0);` ;)

Comment: And also look into `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: @MartinLarsson The point of `BigDecimal` is that it doesn't suffer from approximation or truncation error (for non-recurring decimals). The problem is due to misuse of the interfaces, as described in the answers.

Comment: BigDecimal is a classic example in Java where the contract of compareTo is not consistent with equals and you seemed to have encountered that .

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can't use the `equals()` method to compare `BigDecimals`, like this assertion does. That is because this equals function will compare ***the scale***. If the scale is different, `equals()` will return false, even if they are the same number mathematically.

You can however use `compareTo()` to do what you want:

As @assylias points out, you should also use the `new BigDecimal("22.3")` constructor to avoid double precision issues.

```
BigDecimal expected = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal actual = new BigDecimal("22.3").multiply(BigDecimal.ZERO);
assertEquals(0, expected.compareTo(actual));
```

There is also a method called `signum()`, that returns -1, 0 or 1 for negative, zero, and positive. So you can also test for zero with

```
assertEquals(0, actual.signum());
```

Answer (score 47):

There are 2 issues with your code:

- you should compare BigDecimal with compareTo instead of equals, as advised by the other answers
- but you should also use the string constructor: `new BigDecimal("22.3")` instead of the double constructor `new BigDecimal(22.3)` to avoid double precision issues

In other words, the following code (which correctly uses compareTo) still returns false:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.1).multiply(new BigDecimal(10));
System.out.println(bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0);
```

because `0.1d * 10d != 1`

Comment: @assylias "but you should also use the string constructor: new BigDecimal("22.3") instead of the double constructor new BigDecimal(22.3) to avoid double precision issues" . can you explain the double precision issue?

Comment: @Geek try this `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.1"));` and this `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1d));`. The first one (String constructor) prints `0.1`, whereas the second one (double constructor) prints `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. This happens because a double can't exactly represent 0.1. More about it [on this page for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double).

Comment: @assylias +1 for the clarification.

Answer (score 20):

`equals()` on [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) checks the internal state of `BigDecimal` for comparison

Refer the code below

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    if (!(x instanceof BigDecimal))
        return false;
    BigDecimal xDec = (BigDecimal) x;
    if (x == this)
        return true;
    if (scale != xDec.scale)
        return false;
    long s = this.intCompact;
    long xs = xDec.intCompact;
    if (s != INFLATED) {
        if (xs == INFLATED)
            xs = compactValFor(xDec.intVal);
        return xs == s;
    } else if (xs != INFLATED)
        return xs == compactValFor(this.intVal);

    return this.inflate().equals(xDec.inflate());
}
```

if you want to compare the values use [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)

Change your code to

```
assertEquals(0 , new BigDecimal(0).compareTo(new BigDecimal(22.3).multiply(new BigDecimal(0)));
```

---

**Update:**

Use constructor taking String as a parameter for BigDecimal for accuracy in precision check the related links below

---

**Also See**

- [Getting wrong result for evaluation of 100 * 2.55 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737768/getting-wrong-result-for-evaluation-of-100-2-55-values)
- [Java BigDecimal bugs with String constructor to rounding with ROUND_HALF_UP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368496/java-bigdecimal-bugs-with-string-constructor-to-rounding-with-round-half-up)