# Combining three variables in java

Tags: java, testing, combinations

I have a question to deal with it in java.

My code has three variables: a,b,c respectively, all doubles.
The sum of all variables must be equal 1.

I need to test all the possible combinations in these variables, with values varying from 0.10

Example:

Combination 1:

```
a = 0.20
b = 0.20
c = 0.60
```

Combination 2:

```
a = 0.10
b = 0.10
c = 0.80
```

and so go on.

Is there any framework or lib to automatize this kind of test?

Comment: On a side note, are you using BigDecimal or another arbitrary precision construct to store your values? 0.10, for instance, cannot be stored exactly with a `float` or `double`.

Comment: You just need a nested for loop to generate them. An if-statement to do the check, so why go as far as getting a library to do it?

Comment: I dont know any lib for that but what about assigning a random number between 0 to 1 for a and another random between 0 and 1-a for b and then c will be 1-a-b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While another commenter pointed out that this can be accomplished with a 3-deep nested `for` loop, there might be a more elegant solution, perhaps using a library like [combinatoricslib](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/#2._Permutations_with_repetitions). You could then do this:

```
    ICombinatoricsVector<BigDecimal> originalVector = 
            Factory.createVector(new BigDecimal[] { 
                    new BigDecimal("0.0"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.1"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.2"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.3"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.4"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.5"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.6"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.7"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.8"), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.9")
    });

    Generator<BigDecimal> gen = Factory.createPermutationWithRepetitionGenerator(originalVector, 3);

    for (ICombinatoricsVector<BigDecimal> perm : gen) {
        // values are in perm.getValue(0), perm.getValue(1), and perm.getValue(2)
    }
```

Afterward, you could iterate through each permutation and check the sum with a `for` loop of depth 1.

Note that I have replaced `float`/`double` with `BigDecimal` in order to address [floating point precision/representation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001). Further note that I have used the `String` constructor of `BigDecimal` to avoid [an insipid form of the same precision/representation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368496/java-bigdecimal-bugs-with-string-constructor-to-rounding-with-round-half-up).